# Unexpected results when parsing website with HTMLAgility Pack

Tags: c#, console-application, html-agility-pack

I'm in a situation where I need to parse information from a page, using HTML Agility Pack in a C# Console application, I have the following;

```
public static void ResultsData()
{
    const string url = "https://example.com";
    const string rowXPath = "//*[@class=\"result\"]";

    var web = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = web.Load(url);

    HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(rowXPath);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nodes[i].InnerText);
    }
}
```

The above seems to return the second set of results and I'm unable to figure out as to why?

I'm parsing the information from within a script:

```
<script>
var displayOrder = "ascending";
function NumberedOrder() {
if (displayOrder == "ascending")
{
document.getElementById("Order").innerHTML = "<span class=\"result\">1</span><span class=\"result\">2</span><span class=\"result\">3</span>";
document.getElementById("OrderButton").innerHTML = "Display ascending order";
displayOrder = "desc";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("Order").innerHTML = "<span class=\"result\">3</span><span class=\"result\">2</span><span class=\"result\">1</span>";
document.getElementById("OrderButton").innerHTML = "Display descending order";
displayOrder = "asc";
}
};
</script>
```

I expected to get the following results:

1
2
3

What I'm actually being given:

3
2
1

Any help would be much appreciated, I've viewed similar threads but none of helped me achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you show the actual HTML that it is parsing? You showed us the JavaScript that modifies the page. If that JavaScript is run, and `displayOrder` is not `ascending`, then it will inject the HTML with the elements ordered as 3, 2, 1 and then that's what you would end up parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the parsing, for some obscure implementation reason, is performed from EOF to BOF?

In which case, would the following produce the desired result?

```
for (int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  Console.WriteLine(nodes[i].InnerText);
}
```

This code appears to be unnecessarily complicated, but I don't see any other way around it with the information you have provided, except of course making changes to the Agility Pack's source code and compiling your own version. I have not immediately found a way to pass a parameter to `DocumentNode.SelectNodes` to alter what appears to be the default ordering.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this indeed reverses the result set. However, it is still taking the results from the 'else' rather than the 'if.

Comment: @H3ALY It's not taking the results from the `else`, because that's JavaScript and the HtmlAgilityPack doesn't parse or run JavaScript.

Comment: I see. I'll give it another check on Friday to see if I can come up with anything else. In the meantime: good luck!